# My code for Discord.JS is having a strange error, can you please help me solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For some reason when I type the purge command with a number more than one it gives the error 'DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message' (look at image for full error), can you please help solve this? I suspect because the functions have already been declared so a second time around it gets confused.

Image of error:

[image]

By the way here is my code for the command:

```
 if (msg.content.startsWith("$purge")) {
        if (msg.content.match(/\d+/)) {
            if (isNaN(Number(msg.content.split(' ')[1])) == false) {
                channel = msg.channel
                msg.delete()
                for (f = 1; f <= Number(msg.content.split(' ')[1]); f++) {
                    msg.channel.messages.fetch().then(e => {
                        e.every(function (value) {
                            if (value.deleted == false) {
                                message = value;
                            }
                        })
                        message.delete()
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                if (isNaN(Number(msg.content.split(' ')[1])) == true) {
                    msg.channel.send("Please include an amount of messages to purge in the right place")
                }
                
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!msg.content.match(/\d+/)) {
                msg.channel.send("Please include an amount of messages to purge")
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

Edit: I realised what was happening, still don't know how to fix it withut using bulkDelete()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from this part:

```js
msg.channel.messages.fetch().then((e) => {
  e.every(function (value) {
    if (value.deleted == false) {
      message = value;
    }
  });
  message.delete();
});
```

[`messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise and when it's resolved a collection of messages (you named it `e`). You try to check if every message has a [`deleted`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=deleted) property and if it doesn't, you just assign the message to a (global?) `message` variable. And as you're working inside a for loop in an asynchronous way, the message you want to delete could be already deleted.

There is a [`bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method in discord.js though which you could use for your purge command. You just need to provide the number of messages you want to delete in the channel and it does the rest:

```js
channel.bulkDelete(5)
  .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

You could simplify your code like this:

```js
const prefix = '$';
// remove the prefix and split by spaces
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
// remove the command from the args array
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'purge') {
  if (isNaN(args[0])) {
    return msg.channel.send(
      'Please include an amount of messages to purge in the right place',
    );
  }
  // add an extra to delete the last message with the purge command too
  const amount = Number(args[0]) > 100 ? 101 : Number(args[0]) + 1;

  msg.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true)
  .then((_message) => {
    console.log(`Bot cleared ${_message.size}messages`);
  });
}
```

Comment: I previously used bulkDelete, but the 14 day limit I thought was very unhelpful, I've seen other bots purge messages without that limit. I have a messages variable that was declared at the start of the code, but this is a very helpful answer if I reconsider, thx.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this way -

```js
channel.bulkDelete(5)
  .then(messages => console.log(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```